# ASP.net core install knockout issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-core

I havew created a new Asp.net core project and im trying to install Knockout.js, im doing so by following [Knockoutjs install](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/knockout.html)

Problem is, i add the knockout to my bower (latest version 3.4.0 not 3.3.0).

```
"knockout": "^3.4.0"
}
```

I hit save, then go to the wwwroot/lib folder and Knockout folder is there.
However it looks like this ...
[image: Solution explorer Image]

As you can see there are 2 folder src and build but no knockout.js, infact the whole directory doesnt contain a knockout.js file.

So im wondering whats the issue here? did something change and made the tutorial not valid? Am I doing somethiong stupid here?

EDIT: I have a feeling this is the source and needs building not sure though

EDIT2: Heres the Gruntfile.js located in proj source used in conjuntion with the trask runner as per the tutoriual i was following.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    bower: {
        install: {
            options: {
                targetDir: "wwwroot/lib",
                layout: "byComponent",
                cleanTargetDir: false
            }
        }
    }
});
grunt.registerTask("default", ["bower:install"]);
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-task");
};
```

I think my gruntfile is missing some key stuff here, just not sure what (not well versed in grunt im afraid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bower pulls the whole package and puts it into "bower_packages/package_name" folder. You can force bower to change default destination directory (in your case it is "wwwroot/lib" folder) but it still gets whole package.

In order to put in the "wwwroot/lib" folder only package build results (files mentioned in the package's bower.json main" property) I'm using "[bower-installer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-installer)" tool. It calls bower to get packages and then gets "main" files for each package and put them in destination folder.

#### Update 1

bower.json

```
   {
      "name": "_______",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "~2.1.0",
        "jqueryui": "~1.11.4",
        "knockout": "^3.4.0"
      },
      "install": {
        "path": "wwwroot/lib",
        "sources": {
          "knockout": {
            "mapping": [
              {
                "bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.debug.js": "knockout.js"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Presumable bower and bower-installer packages are installed globally.
Just create bower.json file in any empty folder and run "bower-installer" command from command line in this folder. You should get "bower_components" folder with full package and "\wwwroot\lib\knockout\knockout.js" file. I've just checked it.

Comment: "bower_packages/package_name" i dont see this anywhere in my project?

Comment: Your packages are stored in the “wwwroot/lib” - e.g. “wwwroot/lib/knockout”. Due to the https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html article, "expand the twisty to the left of bower.json, and locate the .bowerrc file. Open it, and notice that the directory property is set to “wwwroot/lib”. This setting indicates the location at which Bower will install the package assets."

Comment: In any case, "bower-installer" will copy files from "directory" property to it's own path setting. To stop using your "wwwroot" as a trash bin, you should change bower's directory setting.

Comment: yeh thats fine but the dist/knockout.js file doesnt exist is what im trying to say.

Comment: It's very strange - I'm using KO 3.4 im my project and I do have two file in the "dist" folder - knockout.js and knockout.debug.js ;) I hope you will trust me without a screenshot.

Comment: yeh its really wierd, how is you grunt setup? maybe thats the issue?  Ill update my question to included the grunt file